# C# webclient: fail to read ajax html content

Tags: c#, ajax, webclient

I want to create a HttpModule to generate html snapshot for google bot, my code is:

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
    // request and response properties.
    var application = (HttpApplication)source;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;

    string escapedFragment = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["_escaped_fragment_"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(escapedFragment))
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://giadinhthinhvuong.com/#/" + escapedFragment);
            if (data != null)
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(data);
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        context.Response.Write(result);
    }
}
```

However it seem not working with ajax content in webpage.

[Here](http://GiaDinhThinhVuong.com?_escaped_fragment_=dang-nhap) you can find my link test.

So my questions are:

1. Is there other way to generate html snapshot for C#?
2. Or is there other way to read ajax content in C#?

Comment: let me clarify. Are you looking for a code that parses or extracts values from html? What do you mean ajax content? Do you mean response from ajax calls?

Comment: Jobert Enamno: "Ajax content" mean my test url have some jquery ajax call to get data from server. And when i use WebClient to get html from test url, it don't have any data because of ajax function doesn't run.